# Script de Python no ejecutado desde Cron

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, crontab, cron

Estoy intentando ejecutar un script de Python desde cron. Manualmente funcional sin problemas. He probado ya todas las soluciones que se pueden encontrar por la web. El archivo de `crontab` es el siguiente:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/miniconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/PAD-S100/PAD-S100-Bloque_Motor/from_repo/event_management.py | /bin/sh /home/pi/PAD-S100/PAD-S100-Bloque_Motor/adddate_to_logs.sh >> home/pi/PAD-S100/PAD-S100-Bloque_Motor/log.log 2>&1
```

`Crontab`, Observaciones:

- El 'PATH' obtenido del comando `echo $PATH` esta ya incluido.
- `event_management` es ejecutable mediante el comando `sudo chmod a+x <file_name>`.

El archivo `log.log` no muestra nada raro.
El archivo de logs del sistema `/var/log/syslog` contiene lo siguiente:

```
Feb 27 15:11:08 raspberrypi cron[21814]: sendmail: Cannot open :25
Feb 27 15:12:01 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Feb 27 15:13:31 2017 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Feb 27 15:12:01 raspberrypi CRON[22209]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/pi/PAD-S100/PAD-S100-Bloque_Motor/from_repo/event_management.py | /bin/sh /home/pi/PAD-S100/PAD-S100-Bloque_Motor/adddate_to_logs.sh >> home/pi/PAD-S100/PAD-S100-Bloque_Motor/log.log 2>&1)
Feb 27 15:12:09 raspberrypi sSMTP[22212]: Unable to set UsesSTARTTILS=""
Feb 27 15:12:09 raspberrypi sSMTP[22212]: Unable to locate
Feb 27 15:12:09 raspberrypi cron[21814]: sendmail: Cannot open :25
Feb 27 15:12:09 raspberrypi sSMTP[22212]: Cannot open :25
Feb 27 15:12:09 raspberrypi CRON[22205]: (pi) MAIL (mailed 178 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)
```

Se puede observar que lo que falla es la linea del `crontab` referente al script de Python. No soy un experto en Linux pero viendo estos logs tengo la impresion de que el problema es algo relacionado con el servicio `sSMTP`. El mismo log de error se repite de forma periodica despues de cada llamada al script de Python por parte de Cron.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Cuál de los cronjobs no se ejecuta?

Comment: @fedorqui La que ejecuta el script de Python, como pone en el titulo de la pregunta, y en el log del sistema. en concreto aquella que llama a ```event_management```. He editado la pregunta para que no haya dudas. Un saludo.

Comment: Si es solamente `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/PAD-S100/PAD-S100-Bloque_Motor/from_repo/event_management.py`, puede ser útil [edit] la pregunta para solo incluir esa entrada. De lo contrario el resto de líneas solo contribuyen a generar ruido y dificultar la comprensión. Por otra parte, recuerda que crontab corre en un entorno muy limitado. ¿Incluye PATH todos los directorios donde tienes binarios necesarios para ejecutar el script?

Comment: @fedorqui Te refieres a los modulos de Python que importo en el script?

Comment: Seguramente más a los binarios que se ejecutan dentro del script sh `adddate_to_logs.sh`. Si no pones la ruta completa, por ejemplo, un `grep` puede no entenderlo. En concreto, busca allá donde operas con la variable `UsesSTARTTILS`, por el error _Unable to set UsesSTARTTILS=""_

Comment: El problema es que no encuentra el programa `sendmail` que sirve para enviar correos. Ejecuta tu línea en una consola, tal vez no sea Python el problema, si no el script que manda el correo.

Comment: ```adddate_to_logs.sh``` funciona sin plroblema en otras lineas de cron que tengo. Aparte, todas las llamadas que se hacen en el script ```.sh``` llevan la ruta completa. Ademas las variables de entorno estan declaradas de manera explicita en el ```crontab```.

Comment: @toledano el script ejecutado manualmente desde el terminal funciona perfectamente. Lo que no entiendo es porque con el ```Cron``` salta ese error relacionado con ```sendmail```.

Comment: Nótese que intentas enviar un email sin especificar correctamente el servidor. Solamente recibe `:25` (el puerto) pero no el servidor. Revisa dónde está este cacho de información.

Comment: El problema de los emails es que Cron intenta enviar un email con el contenido del ```stdout``` y ```stderr``` por defecto, pero si no tienes configurado el cliente de mail produce un error qque queda registrado en ```/var/log/syslog``` en el caso de distribuciones basadas en Debian, o en ```var/log/cron``` en el caso de Fedora.

Comment: Escribiendo en ```crontab``` lo siguiente: ```MAILTO=""``` evitas que cron envie estos emails. Aun con todo esto, el script de Python sigue sin hacer lo que quiero

Comment: No deberías hacer la misma pregunta aquí y en [SO en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488101/python-script-not-executed-from-cron). Parece más un problema de configuración que de python o del cron. Con lo que nos dices no se puede saber. `UsesSTARTTILS` parece un error tipográfico de algún fichero de configuración. ¿No?

Comment: @ChemaCortes porque no deberia? Hay gente que no sabe castellano y viceversa

Comment: @BSP Es más fácil intentarlo en uno de los idiomas y traducir, que sincronizar ambas preguntas que casi nadie se molesta en hacer. Pero tampoco me hagas mucho caso.

Comment: BSP: si encontraste respuesta y no es por la barra delante de `home/`, es mejor que publiques tu solución para que todos aprendamos de ello. Puedes leer al respecto en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de probar varias cosas y leyendo los comentarios de otros usuarios, he encotrado el problema. Es una combinacion de dos errores que no están directamente relacionados, pero unidos hacen complicado el debug.

---

### Primer problema:

El archivo `log.log` contiene entradas de tres `cronjobs` distintos. Por lo tanto no me di cuenta de que había usado el comando `chmod` de manera errónea en el script de Python `event_management`, ya que había multiples mensajes de distintas fuentes. Lo mismo pasa al mirar el archivo `/var/log/syslog`. Cron no es el único que escribe ahí. Por lo tanto puede llevar a confusión el leerlo para hacer debug.

**Conclusión:** Un `cronjob`, un archivo `log`.

---

### Segundo problema:

Tengo dos distribuciones de Python instaladas. Cuando ejecuto el script de manera manual se usa una, y Cron usa otra. Me di cuenta de este error al corregir el primer problema creando varios archivos de log, uno para cada cronjob. El `cronjob` ejecutando el script de Python usaba una distribución de Python que no tenía instalados los módulos necesarios. Por lo tanto daba error al leer el `import...`. Para comprobar mi distribcuion de Python usé:

```
which Python
```

**Conclusión:** Una sola distribucion, y te evitas problemas.

Comment: Perdon por la falta de tildes. Escribo desde un teclado americano.

Comment: Claramente necesitas usar virtualenv :)

Comment: @fedorqui jejeje, soy nuevo con esto del Linux. Seguro que necsito usar muchas cosas que desconozo :D

Comment: BSP: mira este artículo sobre [Virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Básicamente, te permite utilizar una versión de Python determinada para un proyecto específico, instalando solamente los paquetes necesarios.

Comment: @fedorqui gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que le falta la barra / detrás de home/ para que sea una ruta absoluta.

Actualmente está así:

```
....../adddate_to_logs.sh >> home/pi/PAD-S100/......
```

y creo que debería estar así

```
....../adddate_to_logs.sh >> /home/pi/PAD-S100/......
```

Comment: Tienes razon en lo de que falta la barra. Lo he comprobado en mi ```crontab``` actual y si que la lleva. No se si sin ella, daria error. De todas maneras ya he encontrado la solucion. Era una mezcla de varias cosas, incluido el email que envia por defecto Cron cuando hay un error en la ejecucion de ```cron job``` y un problema con las distribuciones de python instaladas, donde el usuario usa una y cron por defecto otra... De todas maneras gracias por tu ayuda.